# QGIS Holux gpx file doesn´t show up

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, gps, gpx, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I  have a problem with displaying the imported gpx file. The gpx file is created in Holux Funtrek 130 PRo. The map I use is from OpenStreetMap. I am sure it is the right map from the location I recorded the gpx file. Everything works fine except the gpx file doesn´t show up. The layer icon is ticked in the layer(s) box. WGS 1984 is set up, both on my gps device and in QGIS. I study geoinformatics, but nothing like this has been taught yet.  We´ve learnt only adding scalebar and all these elementary tasks.

Comment: Can you tell more about your configuration and how you set it up (e.g. how did you import the GPX file? how did you import the OSM data? are you using on the fly-reprojection?). Can you make your GPX file publically available? Have you tried the GPX file in any other tools (e.g. uploading it to an online-OSM editor)?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your layer of interest and choose Zoom to Layer Extent

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the Openlayers plugin to see  a Openstreetmap. In that case, your **project** layer should be in `EPSG:3857`. Check the layer properties of the **GPX** layer by rightclick `-> Set CRS for layer`, if it is really set to `EPSG:4326`.

Both layers must have different CRS to see them aligned.